# Insert bundle into osgi failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, opendaylight

Dear all:

I write a sample plugin and i want insert this bundle into my controller. But error occurs when i start it in the OSGI, it show:

```
gogo: BundleException: The bundle "org.opendaylight.controller.ping.plugin_0.4.0.SNAPSHOT [98]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.opendaylight.controller.sal.binding.api; version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"
```

Referring from this [post page](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html), I think that I've got a newer version of a plug-in without its dependencies.

The error shows that the minimum version number of org.opendaylight.controller.sal.binding.api is `1.1.0`, and mine version is `1.0-1` as i lookup in my directory of `controller/opendaylight/distribution/opendaylight/target/distribution.opendaylight-osgipackage/opendaylight/plugins`.

My question is how to switch the version from `1.0-1` to `1.1`, i can find the `1.1` version of sal.binding.api in my directory: `~/.m2/repository/org/opendaylight/controller/sal-binding-api/1.1-SNAPSHOT`.

As i look into my pom.xml, i foud my dependency is `1.1`:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
      <artifactId>sal-binding-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I think it's very strange.

Great appreciation for anyone's reply!

Best Regards,
Vinllen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin versions should be in the form 'major.minor.micro.build', where 'major', 'minor' and 'micro' are all numbers, 'build' can be anything. So you should have something like 1.1.0.SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem: change the version 1.1 to 1.0-1 in pom.xml. After then , if have any other problems, change the version 1.1 to 1.0-1 with the different jar packet continue.